# How to assign and retrive the value in member variable?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inheritance

I am put/get value in/from subclass B from object of base class A. But I am not able to assign or get the value. My code is:

```
class A
{

};

class B: A
{
    string SID;
};

class C: A
{
    string Name;
};

class D : A
{
    string Name;
};

class E
{
    A a;
    UINT32 AccessLevel;
};

.......

main()
{
    E e;
}
```

Using object of e am trying to get the value of subclass B.

I need to get the SID from the class B?

Thanks,

Comment: Please check the concepts of inheritance. Also the differences between "class" and "object/instance". `B` has no `SID` value, and your program has no `B` instances. And if there were, you could not access it from any `E` instance.

Comment: for c++ you need to use public inheritance such as `class B : public A`, plus you need to declare your variables public too.

Comment: @zahir your comment is misleading. You don't *need* to use public inheritance in C++. It's just that with a class, if you do not specify the access specifier(private/public) when inheriting, it will 'default' to private, while writing `struct B : A` defaults to public inheritance. Secondly, the variables do not *need* to be declared public, they need to be declared `protected` or `public` to be accesible from derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

The C++11 standard 11/3 says:

> Members of a class defined with the keyword class are `private` by default.

at 11.2/2

> In the absence of an access-specifier for a base class [...] `private` is assumed when the class is defined with the class-key class.

and at 11.2/1:

> If a class is declared to be a base
>   class for another class using the `private` access specifier, the `public` and `protected` members of the base
>   class are accessible as `private` members of the derived class.

So what does that mean? First of all:

```
class A {};
class B : A {};
```

Here `A`, by virtue of 11.2/2 is inherited privately. This may be okay if you want to inherit variables and you want to implement getter/setters for a variable only in a derived class, but that's usually considered bad style.

In your case however, as stated by 11/3, your members are not inherited at all because they are private members:

```
class A
{
    public:
        int a; // inherited
    protected:
        int b; // inherited
    private:
        int c; // NOT inherited
};
```

and especially

```
class A { int a; };
```

is equivalent to

```
class A { private: int a; };
```

So you could make your members accessable from *within* your derived classes by making them `public` or `protected` (see 11.2/1):

```
class A { public: int a; };
class B : A {}; // privately inherits a
```

and if you wanted to make it acessable from *outside* of your derived classes you will have to inherit as `public` as well:

```
class A { public: int a; };
class B : public A {}; // publicly inherits a
```

but that's not what you usually would do. It's considered better style to make variables private and expose only getters and setters for those:

```
class A
{
    public:
        int get_a() const { return a_; }
        void set_a(int val) { a_ = val; }

    private:
        int a_;
};

class B : public A {}; // now publicly inherits the getters and setters
                       // but not a_ itself
```